# How to replace text in a table using Jquery(or Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have a table

```
<table id="t">
     <tr>
           <td> fsabcdf </td>
           <td> xyzabcdf </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td> fsabcdf </td>
           <td> xyzabcdf </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td> fsabcdf </td>
           <td> xyzabcdf </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

i want to replace "abc"(in td) with "abc" as in the following

```
<table id="t">
     <tr>
           <td> fs<span class='c2'>abc</span>df </td>
           <td> xyz<span class='c2'>abc</span>df </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td> fs<span class='c2'>abc</span>df </td>
           <td> xyz<span class='c2'>abc</span>df </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
           <td> fs<span class='c2'>abc</span>df </td>
           <td> xyz<span class='c2'>abc</span>df </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

i googled for the solution but didn't find any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be easier to handle this on the server. Is that a possibility here?

Comment: BTW - you didn't find any results because the implementation will probably be different for each use case...

Comment: No @Lix , I should work on only HTML,and Javascript(or jquery), my work is on view and i can't access controller or model.

Comment: @Lix, i found methods like wrap() in jquery but the problem is i am unable select part of text from td ( $(what to write here).wrap() )

Comment: Yes - this is because the `wrap()` command operates on elements and not on parts of text. You won't be able to use `wrap()` in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('td').html(function(i, html){
  return html.replace(/abc/g, '<span class="c2">abc</span>'); 
});
```

This goes through each `<td>`, looks at its text, then replaces every occurrence of `abc` with `abc` wrapped in the span you want.

Comment: The second argument of the `html` callback function contains current HTML of the element, using that can be more efficient that creating jQuery objects (_not the downvoter_).

Comment: Thanks for your soutions @BillCriswell, its working but its replacing only first occurence of 'abc' in td, so i have changed that to        replace(/abc/g, '');
Now its changing every occurence

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$('td').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('abc', '<span class="c2">abc</span>'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ru8XX/

Comment: this worked for me, not the marked answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#t td').each(function(){
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace("abc","<span class='c2'>abc</span>") );
});
```